# Obter maior valor separado conforme o código do produto em datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

Meu projeto possui um `DataTable` com quatro colunas. Eu gostaria de saber como  obter apenas os itens desse `DataTable` que, conforme sua ocorrência, possui a maior quantidade separada?

Por exemplo:

```
Codigo|Descricao|Emgalagem|Separado
1010  |Celular  |12       |1
1010  |Celular  |12       |2
1010  |Celular  |12       |3
2020  |Tablet   |8        |1
2020  |Tablet   |8        |2
2020  |Tablet   |8        |3
2020  |Tablet   |8        |4
3030  |Laptop   |6        |1
```

Neste caso o 1010 com três itens separados e o 2020 com quatro itens e o 3030 com apenas 1 item. Como posso realizar isso?

Comment: os dados vem duma tabela em SQL?

Comment: Não, eles vem como parâmetro de um form

Comment: qual seria a coluna que precisa obter o maior valor? A separado?

Comment: sim, é a separado...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente algo como:

```
var result = from tab in dt.AsEnumerable()
          group tab by tab["Codigo"] into groupDt
             select new 
              { 
                Codigo = groupDt.Key,
                Max=groupDt.Max((r)=> int.Parse(r["Separado"].ToString()))
              };

    foreach(var item in result)
            Console.WriteLine(item.Codigo + ": " +item.Max);
```

coloquei no fiddle para melhor visualização: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hq2LCz

Comment: Atualizei a forma, agora esta da forma que voce precisa

Comment: Boa tarde LeoHenrique... seu código funcionou! muito obrigado pela ajuda :)